# How to create RecyclerView using List<String>?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a RecyclerView of String List. But I am unable to get the data into the recyclerView. I am able to create the string ArrayList. I have checked it.

Here is my adapter code:-

```
class SearchPlaceAdapter(
    private var mContext: Context,
    private var mPlaces: List<String>,
    private var isFragment: Boolean = false,
): RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchPlaceAdapter.ViewHolder>(){


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.rv_search_place, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        holder.place.text = mPlaces[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mPlaces.size
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var place: TextView =itemView.findViewById(R.id.searchPlaceTV)
    }

}
```

here is my fragment code:-

```
 placesRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)
        placesRecyclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        placesList = ArrayList()
        placesAdapter =
            context?.let { SearchPlaceAdapter(it, placesList as ArrayList<String>, true) }
        placesRecyclerview.adapter = placesAdapter


searchButton.setOnClickListener {
    searchPlaces()
}


private fun searchPlaces() {
    val placesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Places")

    placesRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(datasnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (datasnapshot.exists()) {
                (placesList as ArrayList<String>).clear()

                for (snapshot in datasnapshot.children) {
                    (placesList as ArrayList<String>).add(snapshot.key!!)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Error Occurred.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

    })
}
```

here is the JSON snippet:-

```
  "Places": {
    "India": true
  }
```

I don't know why I am not able to get the data. I have tried everything but it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you finished getting the data from the Realtime Database, actually when your `placesList` already contains all the objects that are returned by your query, then you have one more operation to perform, which is to inform the adapter about the changes using:

```
for (snapshot in datasnapshot.children) {
    (placesList as ArrayList<String>).add(snapshot.key!!)
}
placesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); //Notify the adapter.
```

As you can see, the last line of code should be added right after the for loop ends.